# Wave packets in Dirac equation

Tags: wavefunction, dirac-equation, time-evolution

Gaussian wave packets remain Gaussians after evolution in case of the Schrodinger equation. It is a very useful property of these wave packets. I don't think the same is true for a Gaussian wave packet evolving according to Dirac equation. Are there any special kind of wave packets that retain their form while evolving under Dirac equation (or Weyl equation)?

Comment: I made that statement based on what is given [here](http://www-classic.uni-graz.at/imawww/vqm/articles/dirac1/dirac1.pdf). Simulations show that Gaussians with non-zero momentum split into two modes and propagate in opposite directions